# Nested For-loop function objectivenot accomplished

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a problem regarding nested looping. I need to do Row 1 - Row 2, Row 1 - Row 3 etc for each sample. Then looping to Row 2 - Row 3 etc. with no duplicates (Row 4 - Row 4) or combination repeats(Row 4 - Row 3). Next, I would need all of the output to be placed into an excel document.

Currently with the code below, I was only able to achieve the loop for Row 1 - Row(n).

```
set.seed(1) 
df <- matrix(sample.int(10, size = 10*5, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 4)
print(df)
df <- as.data.frame(df)  # tabulate as dataframe 
my_list <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for( j in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (i != j) {
      if(i < j){ 
      my_list[[i]] <- df[i,] - df[j,]
      }
    }
  }
}
df1 <- rbindlist(my_list, fill=TRUE)
```

I assumed that having:

```
if (i != j) {
      if(i < j){
```

would be enough but its not giving me what I want.

Please help!

Comment: just do `if(i<j)`... and your code does work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combn` to get all possible combinations and subtract them.

```
do.call(rbind, combn(seq(nrow(df)), 2, function(x) {
  df[x[1], ] - df[x[2], ]
}, simplify = FALSE)) -> result

write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```